# Issue with combobox autocomplete in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autocomplete

I have a combobox populated by a datatable, the code searches for a text string located at any position of the field while the user is writing, so far no problem.

So the problem is: When I write the third character the combobox autocompletes with the first result, and there is no way to type anything else.

I have tried already using all `AutocompleteMode` & `AutocompleteSourse` properties settings and combinations.
That’s why I’m asking for help.
The code is below:

```
Private Sub ComboListadoRemitente_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)   Handles ComboListadoRemitente.KeyUp

    Dim strText As String

    strText = ComboListadoRemitente.Text

    If Len(strText) > 2 Then

        ComboListadoRemitente.DataSource = dtListado.Select("listado LIKE '%" & strText & "%'")

        ComboListadoRemitente.DroppedDown = True

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got something that works well, it is not the final version, surely can be further improved, here is the code:

```
Public Sub ComboListadoRemitente_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboListadoRemitente.KeyUp

        Dim strText As String

        strText = ComboListadoRemitente.Text


        If ComboListadoRemitente.Text = "" Then

            ComboListadoRemitente.DataSource = Me.dtListado

            ComboListadoRemitente.ValueMember = "Id"

            ComboListadoRemitente.DisplayMember = "listado"

            ComboListadoRemitente.SelectedIndex = -1

            ComboListadoRemitente.DroppedDown = False

        End If



        If Len(strText) > 2 Then

            ComboListadoRemitente.DataSource = dtListado.Select("listado LIKE '%" & strText & "%'")

            ComboListadoRemitente.ValueMember = "Id"

            ComboListadoRemitente.DisplayMember = "listado"

            If ComboListadoRemitente.Items.Count <> 0 Then

                ComboListadoRemitente.DroppedDown = True

                ComboListadoRemitente.SelectedIndex = -1

                ComboListadoRemitente.Text = ""

                ComboListadoRemitente.SelectedText = strText

                strText = ""

                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default


            Else

                ComboListadoRemitente.DataSource = Me.dtListado

                ComboListadoRemitente.ValueMember = "Id"

                ComboListadoRemitente.DisplayMember = "listado"

                ComboListadoRemitente.SelectedIndex = -1

                ComboListadoRemitente.Text = ""

                ComboListadoRemitente.SelectedText = strText

                strText = ""

                ComboListadoRemitente.DroppedDown = False



            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```